# Place Floating Div evenly and horizontally

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I want to place 3 div's evenly inside another div. However, I can't get rid of the right margin for the last floating box. Also, the spaces between them do not look right to me.

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="b">b1</div>
        <div class="b">b2</div>
        <div class="b">b3</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.page{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
}


.box{
    background-color: blue;
}

.b{
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    background-color: #999;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}
```

The code is located at http://jsfiddle.net/u6KqK/

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: You might have a hard time since 30% = 90% of the dive the the 3% margin = 99% so 1% still remaining.

I would personally forget about the float and use display:inline-block
with text align center on the parent. that way all the divs should be centered and on the same line

Answer (score 0):

You're using 99% (30+30+30+3+3+3) of the parent div, not 100%, thus why the right margin of the right-most div appears to be 4%. Here are a couple solutions:

1) set the `margin-right` to use the final percent:

```
.b{
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 3.3333333333%;
    margin-right: calc(10%/3);
    background-color: #999;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Since older browsers don't support `calc`, I included a fallback that will be identical for essentially every scenario. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6KqK/7/

2) Add a 1% margin to the left of the first div:

```
.b:first-of-type{
    margin-left:1%
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6KqK/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second class to the middle div and add the margins to that class. That way it only gets applied to the middle class.

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="b">b1</div>
        <div class="b middle">b2</div>
        <div class="b">b3</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.page{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
}


.box{
    background-color: blue;
}

.b{
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #999;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}
.middle{
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6KqK/9/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the left-most div on the actual left it would make sense to have the right-most also to the far right with zero margin

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/u6KqK/12/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="b">b1</div>
        <div class="b">b2</div>
        <div class="b">b3</div> /* cleafix div removed */
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden; /* quick clearfix */
}


.box{
    background-color: blue;
}

.b{
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 5%;  /* (100% - 3x30%)/2 */
    background-color: #999;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}
.box div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```